# Does not execute the code after allocation of memory

Tags: c

Compile does not execute even a single "printf" function after I allocate some memory for an array of structures, why does it happen?

```
int main(){
    setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    int entry_size;
    int all_ids [101] = {0};
    int studentSize;
    int max;
    student* Students = readStudents ("students1.txt", &entry_size, all_ids, &studentSize);
    printf ("%i \n", entry_size);
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= entry_size; i++){
        if(all_ids[i] != 0) studentSize++;
    }
    topThreeAvg *averages = malloc(studentSize * (sizeof(topThreeAvg)));
    for (i = 1; i <= entry_size; i++){
        printf("%s %s %i %i\n", (Students + i) -> firstName, (Students + i) -> secondName, (Students + i) -> ID, (Students + i) -> grade);
    }
    max = getMaxGrade (Students, entry_size);
    printf ("Max grade is %i \n", max); 
    fillAllStudentsAvgGrades (&averages, Students, entry_size, all_ids);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compilation doesn't *run* the code - it generates an executable, which can then be used to run the code. So, first compile the code (and fix any errors or warnings that occur), then run the executable (and fix any runtime errors that occur).

Comment: Why are you changing the stream buffering scheme in this code using setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); Comment out this and try

Comment: It appears the loops in the code, as shown, have an off-by-one error.    Array indexing in C starts at zero, not one.   The loops use array indexing starting at one.    The behaviour of both loops is therefore undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
topThreeAvg *averages = malloc(studentSize * (sizeof(topThreeAvg)));
for (i = 1; i <= entry_size; i++){
    printf("%s %s %i %i\n", (Students + i) -> firstName, (Students + i) -> secondName, (Students + i) -> ID, (Students + i) -> grade);
}
```

You are accessing out of bound, note that range of array index is `0...n-1` but you are accessing `1...n`.

Thus change the loops as below everywhere,

```
for (i = 0; i < studentSize ; i++){
```

---

**side note::** Also

```
Students[i].ID
```

produces better readability than

```
(Students + i)->ID
```

Comment: I followed your advice, but it still does not execute anything written after "topThreeAvg *averages = malloc(studentSize * (sizeof(topThreeAvg)));"

Comment: it should `studentSize ` in for loop not `entrySize`.

Comment: It is not a problem, actually, the problem is that, for example, if I write "printf("hello");" after the "topThreeAvg *averages = malloc(studentSize * (sizeof(topThreeAvg)));"  it won't output "hello" in the console

Comment: did you try adding `\n` after `hello`? `printf("hello\n");`